# Converting a Date Format to YYYYMM in Cognos Report Studio

Tags: sql, datetime, cognos, cognos-8, cognos-10

I have a date column in a format `12 May, 2014` I want to convert that into `yyyymm/ 201405` format. 
i tried multiple options like

```
extract(year, sys_date)*100 + extract(month, sys_date))*100
cast(extract( year, sys_date), varchar(4)) + cast(extract( month, sys_date), varchar(2))
```

This one works but returns me in `YYY,YMM` format.

```
CAST(to_char(sys_date, 'YYYYMM'), INT )
```

For the above two, it gives an error:

```
 An error occurred while performing operation 'sqlOpenResult' status='-28'
```

Can some one please guide. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't change it in the SQL. Use the report cell itself to choose a display format.

Comment: @Zane: Could you please elaborate? It's been just few days I have started working in Cognos so can't understand what you mean. Thank you

Comment: Are you displaying these dates in a column or on a graph?

Comment: I want it in a column

Comment: Then use the columns properties to change the format of the date displayed.

Comment: Select the column in the report.  In the properties pane on the left, you can modify the format.  Click in the **Data Format** field, select the type as Date.  Then you can format it however you want.

Answer (score 1):

I got what I was looking for. This is what I did:

```
translate(CAST(to_char(sys_date, 'YYYYMM'), varchar(6) ), ',' , ' ')
```

I am sure there would be a better way to get the result but for now I would use this SQL as it gives me what I want :)

Comment: Yes I could do that, but I wanted that field not in the final report but to perform some calculations and joins internally.

Comment: Yeah but if you are using that column for joins why change the date format?

Comment: The column I was joining with was in 'YYYYMM' format. Hence had to change it to that format internally.

Comment: I think you did it backwards. The internal representation should always be the temporal data (like a date value). "Format" is something for the presentation side. If I want a steak I get a steak, I don't try to reassemble hamburger into the shape of a steak.

Comment: Then why not fix the one that's not in a DATE datatype. 
This would be like if you had a flat tire and instead of putting on a new tire you flattened another tire so it would ride even.

Comment: Ok I get it...It's just that, i have recently started coding and programming and when this worked the way I wanted to...voila! it made me happy...But i totally get your point...nd will work to make it more smooth than riding on a flat tire

Answer (score 0):

I did it so.

```
substring(cast(substring(cast([sys_date];char(7));1;4)||substring(cast([sys_date];char(7));6;2);char(6));1;6 )
```

to me worked

Answer (score 0):

Select the column in the report. In the properties pane on the left, you can modify the format. Click in the Data Format field, select the type as Date. Then you can format it however you want.